# How to measure wind speed in a wind tunnel

Tags: wind-tunnel

I'm currently building a wind tunnel that moves air at hundreds of meters per second. How do I cheaply measure the wind speed?

Comment: What are your budget and accuracy requirements?  There are lots of metrics that can be cheap (pitot tube, anemometer, PIV), but it really depends on what you intend to do with the tunnel.

Comment: If you have the ability to make air move at "hundreds of meters per second" an anemometer shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple pitot tube attached to a fluid level balance can do this, if you can develop a pressure differential vs airspeed reference for it.

Answer (score 0):

An anemometer will work, but do not place it downstream of any turbulence-producing object, or you may destroy it.  Speaking from experience.

Comment: An anemometer was good enough for the Wright wind tunnel.